# loading models in FastAPI projects at startup

Tags: deployment, fastapi

so I'm currently working on a FastAPI project that serves multiple NLP services. To do so I want to provide different models from spacy as well as huggingface.

Since those **models are quite big** the inference time when **loading the models for each post request is quite long**. My idea is to **load all the models on FastAPI startup (in the app/main.py)**, however, I'm not sure, whether this is a good choice/idea or if there a some drawbacks to this approach since the models will be in the cache(?). (Info: I want to dockerize the project and deploy it on a virtual machine afterwards)

So far I wasn't able to find any guidance on the internet, so I hope to get a good answer here :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are deploying your app using `gunicorn` + `uvicorn` worker stack. You can use `gunicorn`'s `--preload` flag.

From the documentation of [**gunicorn**](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)

> preload_app
>
> --preload Default: False
>
> Load application code before the worker processes are forked.
>
> By preloading an application you can save some RAM resources as well
> as speed up server boot times. Although, if you defer application
> loading to each worker process, you can reload your application code
> easily by restarting workers.

You just need to use `--preload` flag with your running options.

```py
gunicorn --workers 2 --preload --worker-class=uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker my_app:app
```

Comment: Hey Yagiz, 

thanks for your answer - so instead of loading the models in the "main.py" I should stick to my current code and just start the app with gunicorn and the --preload flag set? 

**FYI: Currently I load the models with a custom class that is called when an POST request is made.**

p.s. I can't give upvotes yet :(

Comment: Hey, i think you can use singleton approach. Declare the model once in your `main.py`. Then use that, it will load the model once in the memory, as far as i understand you are creating a new class instance for every request which means you are loading that model in the memory for every request, right?

Comment: exactly! I'll change my code according to your recommendation - thanks alot! :)

Comment: @YagizDegirmenci: can you please verify if I am understanding this right? If we use the `--preload` flag, the main gunicorn thread loads the application on bootup, and then when the workers get forked, they get a copy of the application? If that is the case, would the application loaded by the workers share the same memory space? Are there any caveats to this approach that I need to be aware of? Thank you.

Comment: @coczor Did you try the singleton approach? How did you make the model objects available via API router?