# FastApi: How to define a global variable once

Tags: python, fastapi, asgi

I want to define a dict variable once, generated from a text file, and use it to answer to API requests.

This variable should be always available till the end of server run.

In an example below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

def init_data(path):
    print("init call")
    data = {}
    data[1] = "123"
    data[2] = "abc"
    return data

data = init_data('path')

@app.get('/')
def example_method():
    # data is defined
    return {'Data': data[1]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(f'example_trouble:app', host='localhost', port=8000)
```

I will get:

```
init call
init call
INFO:     Started server process [9356]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://localhost:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and request to localhost:8000 wouldn't raise any errors

How should I define a variable once, that would be accessed as a global variable to any request? Is there a common way to define it once and use it?

requirements if necessary:

```
fastapi==0.68.1
pydantic==1.8.2
starlette==0.14.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
```

Comment: What is the problem of your approach?

Comment: Creating a dict from a big file twice could be a real problem

Comment: try preloading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636962/loading-models-in-fastapi-projects-at-startup?rq=1

Comment: @Alex do you have any idea why your method is executed twice?

Comment: I suppose this is due to the asynchronous nature of the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [FastAPI startup event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event) to define the variable `data` once on app startup.

An example similar to what you provided in your question:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
data = {}

@app.on_event('startup')
def init_data():
    print("init call")
    path='/an/example/path'
    data[1] = "123"
    data[2] = "abc"
    return data

@app.get('/')
def example_method():
    # data is defined
    return {'Data': data[1]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(f'example_trouble:app', host='localhost', port=8000)
```

When running the app, you'll see that function is only executed once:

```
INFO:     Started server process [37992]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
init call
```

Comment: It almost works. I changed  "data = {}" to "global data" and defined global variable in init_data(). In this example, data variable is redefined to an Empty dict again after init_data method call

Comment: can you define global variables inside the startup loop instead of creating a data object? What would be the pros / cons of that approach?

Answer (score 3):

The current recommended approach to this in FastAPI is [lifespans](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan). Here's an example (untested):

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI

data = {}

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Init
    print("Startup")
    data["path"] = '/an/example/path'
    data[1] = "123"
    data[2] = "abc"

    yield

    # Shutdown
    print("Shutdown")
    data.clear()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get('/')
def example_method():
    # data is defined
    return {'data': data[1]}
```